# Guava Function in interfaces

Tags: java, interface, functional-programming, guava

I am going through an old code base of Java 6 and I see this in one of the interfaces

```
public static Function<Model, Map<? extends Class<? extends Feature>, Map<String, String>>> getRequiredFeatures = new Function<Model, Map<? extends Class<? extends Feature>, Map<String, String>>>() 
{
  @Override
  public Map<? extends Class<? extends Feature>, Map<String, String>> apply(final Model input) 
  {
     return input.getRequiredFeatures();
  }
};
```

Besides lots of Generic types, what I didnt understand is what is exactly being done here. Arent we just allowed to declared method signatures in interfaces? SO how does this work. I also see a lot of this in the code which also I dont understand:

```
public static Function<Model, Set<Model>> unwrap = function(FuncitoGuava.<Model, Set<Model>>functionFor(callsTo(Model.class).unwrap()));
```

This might be a noob question as I am pretty new to FP and Guava in general. So please go easy on this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first code snippet is not a method declaration. It is a field declaration.

The field is of the type [com.google.commons.base.Function<F, T>](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) which is an interface and therefore you need to implement all the methods of this interface (which is here in fact `public Map<...> apply(final Model input)`)

Comment: There is a method `apply`, but it is part of the anonymous `Function` class, not the interface itself.